# Derivative tests question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Show that $k(x) = \sin^{-1}(x)$ has $0$ inflections $2$ critical points $0$ max/min

I find that the first derivative is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Second derivative is $$\frac{x}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

I don't know why it has $2$ critical points, I can find only one at second derivative which $x = 0$. I don't know the other one.

There is no min/man because I can't find $x$ values in first derivative.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet???

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: I already tried my best. That is all i got.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> In mathematics, a critical point or stationary point of a differentiable function of a real or complex variable is any value in its domain where its derivative is 0 or undefined

As you can easily see, $f'(x)$ is undefined on $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

I think you might have misunderstood the concept of a critical point for that of an inflection point.